# asp.net MVC Custom errors, server try to use shared/error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a strange problem - on localhost my errors are served by `ErrorsController` - `Error404` for 404 and `General` for other errors. Everything works perfectly.

But when I upload application on server, only 404 works nice. Other errors are forced to use old `Shared/Error.cshtml` instead of action `General` in `ErrorsController`.

ErrorsController:

```
public class ErrorsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult General(Exception exception)
    {
        HandleErrorInfo toReturn = new HandleErrorInfo(exception, "Errors", "General");
        return View("Error",toReturn);


        //return Content("General failure", "text/plain");
    }

    public ActionResult Http404()
    {
        return View("404");
        //return Content("Not found", "text/plain");
    }

    public ActionResult Http403()
    {
        return View("403");
        //return Content("Forbidden", "text/plain");
    }

}
```

Here is my Global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
        var httpException = exception as HttpException;
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError();
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values["controller"] = "Errors";
        routeData.Values["action"] = "General";
        routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;

        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        if (httpException != null)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
            switch (Response.StatusCode)
            {
                case 403:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Http403";
                    break;
                case 404:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Http404";
                    break;
            }
        }

        IController errorsController = new ErrorsController();
        var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
        try
        {
            errorsController.Execute(rc);
        }
        catch (Exception xx)
        {
            Response.Write(xx.Message);
            //HttpContext.Current.ClearError();
            //Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx", false);
            return;

        }
     }
```

What is the problem? Why on localhost everything works fine, but when I go into server only 404 works as it should and Error page are displayed from `Shared/Error.cshtml`?

Comment: Do you have any weird transforms going on in Web.Config.Release (when you deploy in release mode, that transform will be run

Comment: I edited question to be more specyfic - I upload application (as always) instead of deploy in release mode. I don't have `Web.Config.Release` - just `web.config` - I deleted unnecessary files for testing.

Comment: Most likely, an error was generated trying to display the error (sounds like a bad joke, I know). If it falls through to your `General` error action, but then encounters another error there, it will fallback to the default, static error page. If you're not doing so already, you should log the exceptions as a they occur (to a simple text file or you can use something more robust like ELMAH), and then check the log to see what's happening in this scenario.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, please look at edit now. I had a problem, when `errorsController.Execute()` throw an error, and then it use default server error. So I put that part of code in try/catch. Now it looks like that Application_Error doesn't run when Error occures (only on server). It is a litle bit strange, because the same code works on localhost perfectly, and the same "test" error occures in /Errors/General, not in /Shared/Error..